# Unsplit line Reversing Line Direction

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dissolve

I am using the unsplit line tool and I noticed that the direction of the lines with multiple segments is getting switched the opposite direction while the single sections seem to continue in the proper direction.

I have enclosed two images showing what I mean. The green lines are the split street centerlines which split at each intersection. The pink lines are the unsplit street centerlines.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/FHBareo.png]  (Green lines by themselves)

[image: http://i.imgur.com/6MzdA14.png]  (Pink lines over the green lines)

You can see on Anne St, First St and Second St, that the direction was flipped whereas Burton Pl, Bluff St and Wantland St remained in the proper direction.  I need them to remain in the original direction as it relates to our start and end address ranges.

Comment: Are you using a dissolve field?

Comment: I didn't. I was using the unsplit tool.  I think you just answered my issue.  Thank you so much!!! :)